# sparse matrix to ijv format

Tags: python, scipy

Is there an efficient way to represent a sparse matrix as ijv (3 arrays : row, column, value) form.
Using nested loop seems very naive and slow for large matrices.
The code comes from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sparse-matrix-representation/):

```py
# Python program for Sparse Matrix Representation
# using arrays

# assume a sparse matrix of order 4*5
# let assume another matrix compactMatrix
# now store the value,row,column of arr1 in sparse matrix compactMatrix

sparseMatrix = [[0,0,3,0,4],[0,0,5,7,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,2,6,0,0]]

# initialize size as 0
size = 0

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        if (sparseMatrix[i][j] != 0):
            size += 1

# number of columns in compactMatrix(size) should
# be equal to number of non-zero elements in sparseMatrix
rows, cols = (3, size)
compactMatrix = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]

k = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        if (sparseMatrix[i][j] != 0):
            compactMatrix[0][k] = i
            compactMatrix[1][k] = j
            compactMatrix[2][k] = sparseMatrix[i][j]
            k += 1

for i in compactMatrix:
    print(i)

# This code is contributed by MRINALWALIA
```

I am going to print sparse matrix to file in ijv form and read it in C++.
scipy.sparse.coo_matrix just give me:

```
print(coo_matrix([[0,0,3,0,4],[0,0,5,7,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,2,6,0,0]]))
  
  (0, 2)    3
  (0, 4)    4
  (1, 2)    5
  (1, 3)    7
  (3, 1)    2
  (3, 2)    6
```

with `np.where()` I can get the index of nonzero elements, but how about the `v` array?

Probably do you know a more efficient method (I am not going to use swig, ... to wrap the code)?

**Edit**

```py
size=np.count_nonzero(sparseMatrix)
rows, cols = np.where(sparseMatrix)
compactMatrix = np.zeros((3, size))
for i in range(size):
    compactMatrix[0][i] = rows[i]
    compactMatrix[1][i] = cols[i]
    compactMatrix[2][i] = sparseMatrix[rows[i]][cols[i]]

print(compactMatrix)
```

That's what I thought finally.

Comment: Have you looked at the `coo_matrix` docs?  Paid attention to its `data`, `row` `col` attributes?

Comment: That's what I was looking for.